# How does lock-based concurrency control in sql work when multiple objects hold a shared lock and one wants to upgrade to exclusive?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking, deadlock

I am trying to understand how transactions work with locks in sql and watched [this great tutorial on youtube](http://youtu.be/a9A7gzam5Io).

I don't understand what happens though if 2 different transactions get a shared lock on the same object, and then one or both of them then want to upgrade to an exclusive lock on the object to write to it.

What would happen on the example at 1:12:55 in the video?

Would it be classed as a deadlock and would one of the transactions have to roll back? Surely one of them can't wait at the point of wanting the exclusive lock and remove it's shared lock, and then continue when the first transaction finishes, because locks cannot be removed until the end of the transaction can they?

Cheers.

Comment: You need to be careful, this is very dependent on the RDBMS. Different RDBMS implement the locking model differently. Which RDBMS you have in mind?

Comment: I am using mysql for the project I am working on. The specific problem I was trying to solve, and I think is now solved, is discussed at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44007/discussion-between-tom-jenkinson-and-pinnym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction wanting the exclusive lock would have to wait until all other shared locks were removed before it can take effect.  In this case, it would wait for the other transaction to release its shared lock, after which it would obtain an exclusive lock.

Thus, if the other transaction were held up by the initial transaction for some other reason, this would result in a deadlock.  Because of this, a good DB design should try to ensure that the initial transaction would not block anything while waiting for an exclusive lock.

Comment: So if t2 waits until t1 finishes so that all other shared locks are released, doesn't this mean that t2 will then continue but the object A that it previously read would now be incorrect because t1 changed it before it committed and released it's exclusive and shared lock?

Comment: If t2 continues after t1 finishes without starting from the beginning again then isn't the outcome the same as the outcome in the table, meaning the wrong answer at the end?

Comment: Oh wait so in this example there would be a deadlock because there is a write to the same object in both transactions yes? If t1 didn't actually need to write anything then it would work fine because when t2 resumed, nothing that it is looking at would have changed values. Cheers!

Comment: @TomJenkinson - yes, the worst case scenario here is a deadlock.  However, this can be avoided if the blocking shared lock was never obtained. An exclusive read lock (in mysql that would be 'SELECT ... FOR UPDATE') would skip the shared lock altogether and avoid the deadlock in this example.

Comment: So is a shared lock the default for transactions in mysql as soon as something is read? Or is the default no locking at all?

And also so you're saying in that example the first R(A) in T1 should be a select with FOR UPDATE, which would then cause T2 to wait before it could even read A until the first transaction finished? I presume this exclusive lock would then remain until the end of the transaction before being released just like shared locks?

Comment: @TomJenkinson - in mysql InnoDB, by default (REPEATABLE_READ mode), a read inside a transaction does not perform any lock whatsoever.  It does however, guarantee a consistent non-locking read that will not change in value during the course of the transaction (MySQL uses MVCC to accomplish this).  Because no locks are acquired, it does not guarantee that the data isn't being changed by another transaction during this time.  To obtain a shared lock, you would need to call 'SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE'.

Comment: And yes, all locks taken by the transaction are released when the entire transaction (not just checkpoints) are committed or rolled back.

Comment: @TomJenkinson - it may be helpful for you to know that this video was discussing transactions, locking, and isolation in a _general_ context, not specific to any DB vendor implementation.  To understand how you would best operate a specific RDBMS, like InnoDB, you'll need to study the vendor specific documentation on this.

Comment: That's great thanks. This is a more specific question to what I'm working on so might not be best suited to this but I am trying to build a tree structure (files and folders) in a mysql table using the information on http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/ and have it all working but I want to make sure that I protect from someone inserting another node whilst a node is being removed and the lft and rgt values for all other nodes are being updated to close the gap. Would this require locking the entire table with LOCK TABLE [table] UPDATE?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44007/discussion-between-tom-jenkinson-and-pinnym)